# Objective-C/iPhone - Reading a word from text file. Looping through if word exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loops, nsarray

I'd like to create a list of explicit words in a text file. I then want to be able to read and loop through this file on the iPhone. What would be the best way to do this?

e.g.,

```
explicit.txt

hello
world
freddy
jason
foo
bar
```

Then just before I save the information I'd like to popup a message to notify the user that a particular word is explicit.

Comment: The answers to this question will be all over the map because you don't say how big the list is, or state clearly what you're doing with it. If you're just asking for ways to read a file line by line in Cocoa in general, that's one question. If you are asking about the most *efficient* way to manage this specific kind of functionality for some particular size of list, then ask that directly and you'll get really precise answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have too many words, it's better to use a database.
But if they're just some words you can try this idea:

Store the words in `explicit.txt` file in the following format:

> |hello|world|freddy|jason|foo|bar|

Then load the whole text and search for the substring `|word|`.
If you find it then the given word is explicit:

```
NSString *explicitWords = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"explicit.txt"];
if ([explicitWords rangeOfString:@"|word|"].location != NSNotFound) {
   // the given word is explicit.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a SQLite2 database to hold the list of words. I then created functions to check against that explicit word and notify the user.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a property list, instead of a text file.

Check out the programming guide for lots of info.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i